# Список li в jquery.

Tags: jquery

Начинаю перебирать весь список, и все значения `value` складывать.
С этим скриптом всё складывается, но проблема в том, что значение вытаскивает только целое а не дробное.

В чём проблема?

```
$(function(){
    $("#add").on("click", function() {
        var visotaokna = $("#visotaokna").val();
        var shirinaokna = $("#shirinaokna").val();
        var kolvookon = $("#kolvookon").val();
        var pl = ((visotaokna * shirinaokna) * kolvookon) / 1000000;
        if(visotaokna !== '' && shirinaokna !== '' && kolvookon !== '') {
            var elem = $("<li value='" + pl + "'></li>").text(visotaokna + " X " + shirinaokna + " - " + kolvookon + " шт. (" + pl + "кв.м.)");
            $(elem).append("<button class='rem'>X</buttton>");
            $("#mylist").append(elem);
            $("#visotaokna").val();
            $("#shirinaokna").val();
            $(".rem").on("click", function(){

            });

            var sum = 0;
            $("#mylist li").each(function(index, value){
                sum += parseFloat(this.value);
            });

    });
});
```

Comment: дробное число разделено точкой или запятой?

Comment: в value записывается с точкой.

Comment: Дело в том, если вывести значение у одного элемента списка то всё в порядке. Как только перебираю все значения, почему-то дробную часть не читает.

Answer (score 1):

пример расчет суммы. `value`. кстати не валидный атрибут, пользуйте `data-value` и соответствующие методы для работы.

в противном случае для доступа к атрибутам используйте `getAttribute('value')`

```js
$(function(){
   var n = 3;
   while(n--){
     var v = Math.round(Math.random()*100)/10;
     $("<li>").text(v)
            .data('value', v)
            .appendTo("ul");
   }
   
   
   
   var sum = 0;
   $("li").each(function(){
      sum += parseFloat( $(this).data('value') );
   });
   console.log(sum);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>   
</ul>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, teran.